# zero extension of smooth vector field outside it's support is still smooth

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $U$ be some open subset of smooth manifold $M$.If we assume exist some smooth vector field defines on $U$ i.e. $X:U \to TU$ as smooth map such that $\text{supp}X \subset U$.We may take zero extension outside $U$ to get $\tilde{X}$.

prove this vector field $\tilde{X}:M \to TM$ is smooth vector field on $M$.

My attempt:First we need to rewrite $X$ as $U\to TM$ as follows:

$$U\to TU\to\pi^{-1}(U)\to TM$$

where the second map is diffeomorphism as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4085311/360262) shows.

We can see if we define a smooth zero  map (since constant map is always smooth) $X_2:M/\text{supp}X \to TM$  by gluing lemma (which state that if two smooth maps defined on open set agree on intersection then glue then gets an smooth map again) if we glue this smooth map together with $X$ we get smooth map $\tilde{X}:M\to TM$.Moreover it's section of $\pi :TM \to M$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct.

Comment: thanks $\ \ \ $